# win2008 - overide inherited permissions

Tags: file-permissions

having permission issues for 2 users using active directory.

added 2 new users to ourdomain.controller/users folder.

The 2 users were auto. added to the Domain Users Group.

Went to the local G:/ drive on the AD machine. The Domain Users group is read only permission to the G:/ drive, exactly what I want.

Went into G:/rw and edited security/permissions. Removed inherited permissions and added the 2 new users and gave them read/write. Why can't the user write to this folder when the map G:/ ?? Access denied.

I even go to G:/rw, properties/security tab/advanced/effective permissions then select the 2 new users and the full control permission is checked.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: are the share permissions correct?  Or just read only?

Comment: i went to g:/rw properties/sharing/advanced/permissions and added the new users and gave full control

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to fix the share permissions.

Set your share permissions as follows:

```
DOMAIN ADMINS = Full Control

EVERYONE (or DOMAIN USERS) = Write/Modify
```

Then your NTFS permissions will still be in effect and lock down the root directory as you wanted.

It's pretty irrelevant to mess with share permissions at all.  The above is how I set EVERY share and then just use the NTFS permissions to lock down the actual access.

Comment: properties/sharing indicates who can map, properties/security indicates who can read/write. Thanks for the help, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect someone is going to come along and close this as a duplicate, as I'd be shocked if no one ever asked this before, but...

You need to assign both NTFS level permissions (what you're talking about) and share level permissions.  It sounds like your users don't have write access on the share level.

If the other users do have write access, it's possible that they're a member of a Windows security group that these two aren't.

Comment: on the g:/ share level perms, I don't want the 2 new users to have write to root, just g:/rw. do I add the new users with write to root directory?

Comment: What TheCleaner said, basically.  The share itself should be write/modify, the top level of G should not have any permissions beyond read, and then you can add the write privileges to the subdirectory.